# What are these parallel blocks of text called?

Tags: formatting, structure

What are these boxes of text called that interrupt the flow of text with some aside type comment?

[image: Warning aside taken from epub documentation]

[source](https://www.w3.org/publishing/epub/epub-contentdocs.html#sec-contentdocs-reserved-prefixes)

They're usually related to the main body of text, are embedded somewhere nearby in their placement on the page to text holding contextual significance. They're usually a side story, aside, backstory, something attention grabbing like the warning example above. It's usually something a little more beefier than an endnote.

- What are these boxes called that publishers often format into
  documents?
- How are these represented in the ePub format?

Answer (score 1):

These blocks of text that highlight additional or important information are called admonitions in writing. A good readup is presented [here](https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/docs-how-to-document/master/en-us/WritingReST/Admonitions.html).
Hope this helps.

Comment: Is this a well-known use of the term 'admonition'? From the link, it looks to me like it's just a name used by that particular piece of software

Comment: It is not a common word but that's what we tech writers use. It is not just specific to that software. I should have mentioned that I'm sharing that page only because it has a good definition. I couldn't find much details on the web. Most folks just call it out as "notes, warnings, etc." in as many words! See what I could easily find from Google of some techcomm website (the irony!) and some BSD book:
* https://www.technicalcommunicationcenter.com/2016/11/04/notes-cautions-and-warnings-in-technical-writing/
* https://www.freebsd.org/doc/en_US.ISO8859-1/books/fdp-primer/preface-notes.html